# Python Appengine timeframe on datastore request

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a site which has a graph in it, however, I don't want to load the entire graph, I only want to load a small timeframe (eg: 1 hour or 1 day)

This is my dbModel for the graph data:

```
class storage(db.Model):
   feedid = db.StringProperty()
   data = db.StringProperty()
   date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

At the moment, to graph the data, I run this:
(feedid just selects which graph to load)

```
d = storage.all()
d.filter("feedid =", feedid)
d.order('date')
    for p in d.run():
    #Use the data to make a graph
```

So how would I change that to request just a certain timeframe rather than the entire set of data?

I'm quite new to Appengine, so this is probably a simple question, but thanks to anyone who tries to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
import datetime
d = storage.all()
d.filter('feedid =', feedid)
d.filter('date >=', datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 1))
d.filter('date <=', datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 30))
d.order('date')
```

That would give you all `storage` with a date in June, 2013.

Note: If you are just starting out with App Engine, I would strongly recommend using [ndb](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview) instead of db. It has a number of advantages such as automatic caching. The same query as the above in ndb looks like:

```
import datetime
q = storage.query()
q = q.filter(storage.feedid == feedid)
q = q.filter(storage.date >= datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 1))
q = q.filter(storage.date <= datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 30))
q = q.order(storage.date)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response; that worked great! I'm looking into ndb, but I haven't decided if I want to change to that (I've got quite a lot of code in other pages which I'd have to reconfigure to use it)

Comment: @user2370602 Still worth it in the long run... some things are done differently there but the good news is that you are not losing any data.. you can simply switch to `ndb` and continue with your current data as is..